# external object in args of handler

Tags: python, logging

I have a custom handler in my `logging.ini`. This handler requires me to pass a method of another external class as first argument. The logging documentation says I could refer to external objects by prefixing a string with `ext://`: 
[access to external objects docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#access-to-external-objects)

So I'm trying something like this:

```
[handler_rabbitHandler]
class=company.common.logger.GELFRabbitHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('ext://company.common.logger.AMQPFactory.get_connection',)
```

But it seems that in the case of the `args` the `ext://` is not being resolved as described in the documentation. Is there a way to refer to a method on an external object in args?

Note:

Many examples show `sys.stdout` in args, like this:

```
args=(sys.stdout,)
```

If I try the same with our custom object I get an import error, but I don't know how I can import it into the namespace of logging:

```
args=(company.common.logger.AMQPFactory.get_connection,)
```

Results in:

```
NameError: name 'company' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ext://` stuff only works for dictionary based configuration (`dictConfig`), and *not* ini-file based configuration (`fileConfig`), which is what you are using.

You may be able to get rid of the error "'company' is not defined" by ensuring that you set

```
logging.company = company
```

before calling `fileConfig`. But really, you're better off switching to `dictConfig` if you can.